# Optimize Large Switch Statement - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, switch-statement

I have a very large switch statement that handles socket messages from a server. It currently has a little over 100 cases and will continue to grow over time. I feel like I should be doing something more optimized than a switch statement.

My idea:
Have a large array of function callbacks. Then I could simple do something like

```
myArrayOfCallbacks[switchValue](parameters);
```

This should turn something that was O(n) where n is the number of switch cases into constant time right? I would think it would be a pretty good optimization.

Any comments or suggestions on a different method?

Comment: Yep, I always use maps (Object or Dictionary) by switch value as a key instead of switch block when it's possible. Additional bonus this approach is more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling a switch-case on one value, you'd better arrange the possible values into a static array of possible values, and you get another static array of corresponding functions to call. Then you do like this:

```
public static const possibleValues:Array=['one value','two value',...];
// in case of ints, use only the second array
public static const callbacks:Array=[oneFunction,twoFunction,...];
// make sure functions are uniform on parameters! You can use 1 parameter "message" as is
...
var swtichValue=message.type; // "message" is an Object representing the message
// with all its contents
var callbackIndex:int=possibleValues.indexOf(switchValue);
if (callbackIndex>=0) if (callbacks[callbackIndex]) callbacks[callbackIndex](message);
```

So yes, you were pretty right in your guess.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with client realisation that accompanies backend. So you will be able go without collections.

```
if (eventType in responseController) {
    //Before call, you could do secure checks, fallbacks, logging, etc.
    responseController[eventType](data);
}

//Where eventType is 'method' name, 
//for example command from the socket server is 'auth',
//if you have implemented method `auth` in your responseController
//it will be called
```